# Convert a date with bash into mysql format

Tags: bash

I'm front this situation :

**foo.csv**

```
blabla;01/01/2014;13:03:11;01/02/2014;14:16:58
```

So the two first fields correspond to the date of start : `01/01/2014;13:03:11`

The two last fields correspond to the date of end : `01/02/2014;14:16:58`

Finally I desire to obtain :

```
blabla;2014-01-01 13:03:11;2014-02-01 14:16:58
```

Someone have an idea of what to use to get there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no problem to use the Perl oneliner then try this one:

```
cat input.txt | perl -lne '($a,$b,$c,$d,$e) = /^([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)$/g; $b =~ s|(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)/(\d{4})|$3-$2-$1|g; $d =~ s|(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)/(\d{4})|$3-$2-$1|g; print "$a;$b $c;$d $e";'
```

or pushing directly the input file(see at the end of the command) to the `Perl`

```
perl -lne '($a,$b,$c,$d,$e) = /^([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)$/g; $b =~ s|(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)/(\d{4})|$3-$2-$1|g; $d =~ s|(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)/(\d{4})|$3-$2-$1|g; print "$a;$b $c;$d $e";' input.txt
```

This is basically combination of several lines of `Perl` code separated by `;`

Comment: Is it possible to redirect the output to a file with this syntax ?

Comment: @musecz yes. Just use `> output.txt` at the end of the command to redirect it into another file.

Comment: Thanks for your support :) I though it was different with perl

Answer (score 1):

```
line="blabla;01/01/2014;13:03:11;01/02/2014;14:16:58"
OLD_IFS="$IFS"           # Save old value of $IFS
IFS=";"
read blah start_date start_time end_date end_time <<<$line
IFS="/"
read month day year <<<$start_date
start_date="$year-$month-$day
read month day year <<<$end_date
end_date="$year-$month-$day"
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
echo "$blah;$start_date;$start_time;$end_date;$end_time"
```

The `$IFS` stands for Input File Separator. It's used in `read` statements to figure out the breaks in inputs. It normally defaults to space, tab Newline, but you can change it.

I first set it to `;`, so I can divide up your semi-colon separated input. Once I have `$start_date` and `$end_date`, I set IFS to `/` which is my separator for the date string. I then reformat my dates, and reset IFS to its original value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for such formatting:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {FS = OFS = ";" }
{
    split($2, d, /\//)
    $2 = d[3]"-"d[2]"-"d[1]" "$3
    split($4, d, /\//)
    $3 = d[3]"-"d[2]"-"d[1]" "$5
    $0 = $1 FS $2 FS $3
}1' file
blabla;2014-01-01 13:03:11;2014-02-01 14:16:58
```

**Explanation:**

- We set the input and out field separator to `;`
- `split` function splits the second field which is a date in to an array so that we can re-organize it. We pad the next field which is time to this field.
- We perform similar operation on the next date.
- We re-structure our entire line to carry new three fields.
- `1` allows us to print the new formatted line.